# Detecting return on input vs button click in reactive form

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm building a reactive form in Angular with 3 submit buttons on it.

```
<form [formGroup]="sessionForm" (submit)="submitSession($event)">
    <div class="row">
        <label>
            <span>Title</span>
            <input type="text" formControlName="title" [class.required]="markRequired.indexOf('title') >= 0">
        </label>
    </div>
    ... more fields ...
    <div *ngIf="!admin" class="row">
        <button type="submit" (click)="setBtnClicked('submit')" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="admin" class="row">
        <button type="submit" (click)="setBtnClicked('save')" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        <button type="submit" (click)="setBtnClicked('approve')" class="btn btn-success">Save and approve</button>
        <button type="submit" (click)="delete($event, false)" [hidden]="confirmDelete" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
        <button type="submit" (click)="delete($event, true)" [hidden]="!confirmDelete" class="btn btn-danger">Are you sure?</button>
    </div>
    <div [hidden]="!showSuccess" class="msgBox msgBox-success">Your session has been submitted! It will need to be approved before it is listed.</div>
</form>
```

On each button, I've attached a `(click)` handler which triggers a function to track which button is hit:

```
setBtnClicked(value) {
    this.btnClicked = value;
}
```

However, when someone hits return on an input, I notice that the value of `this.btnClicked` is equal to the first button in the form.

I'm not sure how to track when a user hits return or when they hit the button, so I can respond differently, or if my structure is wrong. I'd like to trigger the `submitSession` function on any submit, be it return or button. I did try adding a formControl to the buttons, but that failed.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using a form, pressing enter on an input should run the `submitSession()` method tied to the form, but it's possible it's defaulting to the first submit button on the form. Maybe removing the `submitSession()` as well as the `type="submit"` from the buttons will prevent a form submission based on enter. That way the user would need to actually click a button to trigger something.

Also in the methods where you pass the event in, the following code would detect if it was triggered by an enter key press.

```
if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    console.log('you just clicked enter');
}
```

Comment: I tried to check `keyCode` from the submit event, but it comes up undefined. Also, both the click and the `submitSession` run (the click first, then the `submitSession`).

Comment: Have you tried removing the `submitSession()` as well as the `type="submit"` from the buttons?

Comment: I'll give it a shot, though I thought having both were semantically correct? Isn't that the goal of Angular?

Comment: Yes, but you have multiple submit buttons, which is where the problem is coming from I believe. Only the first one will be executed.

Comment: Makes sense. Though maybe that's the problem? Maybe another solution is a better idea...

Comment: So what is the desired result? On submit the `(submit)="submitSession($event)"` will always run, as well as whatever submit button is selected (or the first one if enter is pressed on the keyboard).